# how to Implement this Abstract Class/properties logic by Interface in C#?

Tags: c#, interface, properties, polymorphism, overriding

I have a abstract Class figures which contains `Abstract properties`
and I am Overriding them in Derived class Rectangle and
Square. Now, iI want to implement this with Interface. But I can't use
constructor and neither I can't Declare the Variable inside the
`Interface`. So, how to implement this using Interface where **Figures Should be Interface** and **Square and Rectangle should be class**?

```
abstract class Figures
{
    int Width;
    int _cs;
    public Figures(int Width)
    {
        CS = Width;
    }

    public abstract int getarea
    {
        get;
    }
    public abstract int getperm
    {
        get;
    }
    public abstract int CS
    {
        set;
    }

    public abstract void display();
}

class Square : Figures
{
    int _CsS;
    public Square(int c) : base(c)
    {
    }

    public override int getarea
    {
        get
        {
            return (_CsS * _CsS);
        }
    }
    public override int getperm
    {
        get
        {
            return (2 * _CsS * _CsS);
        }
    }
    public override int CS
    {
        set
        {
            _CsS = value;
        }
    }

    public override void display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("area={0} and perimeter={1}", getarea, getperm);
    }
}

class Rectangle : Figures
{
    int H;
    int _csr;
    public Rectangle(int H, int W) : base(W)
    {
        this.H = H;
    }

    public override int getarea
    {
        get
        {
            return H * _csr;
        }

    }
    public override int getperm
    {
        get
        {
            return 2 * H * _csr;
        }

    }
    public override int CS
    {
        set
        {
            _csr = value;
        }
    }

    public override void display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("area={0} and perimeter={1}", getarea, getperm);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you keep `abstract class Figures` for the common/standard logic an let it implement a `interface IFigure` in which you declare the publicly available members (properties and methods in this case) of `Figures`?

Comment: u mean Interface-->abstract class figures-->rectangle and Squares   ? @Corak

Comment: Yes, like that. -- What I don't understand is, why you seem to want to get rid of the abstract class (but still have common functionality in inheriting/implementing classes). A common (maybe abstract, but not necessarily) base class for common functionality is a good thing. And that common base class can also implement an interface. It's not a hard "one or the other".

Comment: If Square : Figures & Figures : IFigures then a square and a rectangle is just a plain old IFigures. That's pretty good, if what you're after is both re-use of code and a looslely coupled system. You should probably keep the abstract class.

Comment: @Marcus - Exactly. If `Figures` implements `IFigures` and `Square` and others inherit from `Figures`, then they also implicitly implement `IFigures`.

Comment: could u pls draw a diagram what do iu mean Exactly. @Marcus

Comment: Not exactly a drawing but have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
interface IFigures
{

    int getarea
    {
        get;
    }
    int getperm
    {
        get;
    }
    int CS
    {
        set;
    }

    void display();
}
```

Thenk you can implement this interface from your classes and do your logic inside the class itself. So instead of putting the properties logic inside of your abstract class you will have to write them in your child classes.

```
class Square : IFigures
{
    int _CsS;
    public Square(int c) 
    {
         CS = c;
    }

    public int getarea
    {
        get
        {
            return (_CsS * _CsS);
        }
    }
    public int getperm
    {
        get
        {
            return (2 * _CsS * _CsS);
        }
    }
    public int CS
    {
        set
        {
            _CsS = value;
        }
    }

    public void display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("area={0} and perimeter={1}", getarea, getperm);
    }

    //here you have implemented properties
}
```

Comment: let 'Figures' implement 'IFigures': 'abstract class Figures : IFigures'

Comment: An interface can't contain a constructor. -1.

Comment: @Rajmond i was intializing the Cs property in Figures abstract class how to do it here ?

Comment: You have to add your logic to your child classes becase you cant do that in interface

Comment: @RajmondBurgaj can;t use the Only (which i want in Interface) it is taking it as auto Implemented properties giving error require both get/set

Comment: @DeepakJain you cant use fields in interfaces but anyway in that case it is better to use auto-properties because it would make the code much simpler and clear

Comment: i want to use set only and not get with CS property

Comment: @DeepakJain I am not seeing a problem if you want to make it only as a setter property, can you please explain in more details where is the problem ?

Comment: @DeepakJain - Why do you want `CS` as setter only but still basically re-implement a local value in every inheriting (child-)class to store it and work with it? Do you know that you can have a `public set` so everyone can set it and a `protected get` so that only objects of the class itself or inheriting (child-)classes can access it? -- Or if you really only want a public setter, why not make it a method `public abstract void SetCS(int value);`?

Comment: @Corak i want it t =o be setter only and classes that inherting this it can override the property

Comment: @DeepakJain - Okay, but where is the benefit? A property is syntactic sugar for get and set method. So why go through the "trouble" of using a property where you just as easily could use a method directly?

Comment: i could use the method instead of properties but currently i am learning properties and does not want to return the CS property(Write only)

Answer (score 1):

> so how to implement this using Interface

By definition, an interface won't let you *implement* anything. You can only *specify* things.

So you will have to remove the ctor and the fields from the interface `IFigures` and re-implement them in every class. You could reuse an implementation with a `abstract class FiguresBase: IFigures` but that's not always the best design.

It all depends on why you want the interface and how you will use it.

Answer (score 0):

Your abstract class is a good thing. It lets you re-use code.

Interfaces (i.e. contracts) are also good if you want to achieve a loosely coupled system.

You can use abstract classes and interfaces together, to achieve both code reusability and loosely coupled parts.

```
public interface IFigures
{
  int getarea();
}
public abstract class Figures : IFigures
{
  public abstract int getarea();

  //opportunity for code reuse
  protected int getarea_internal()
  {
    throw new NotimplementedExcpetion();
  }
}

public class Square : Figures
public class Rectangle: Figures
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer
with class Diagram

[Class Diagram of the Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWB2A.jpg)

```
 interface IFigures
    {
        int Getarea
        {
            get;

        }
        int GetPerm
        {
            get;
        }
        int CS
        {
            //get;
            set;
        }
    }
  abstract class Figures:IFigures
    {
        int _Cs;
        public Figures( int _Cs)
        {
            CS = _Cs;
        }

        public abstract int Getarea
        {
            get;

        }
        public abstract int GetPerm
        {
            get;

        }
        public abstract int CS
        {
            //get;
            set;
        }
        public abstract void display();

    }
class Circle:Figures
    {
        int _r, _csc;
        public Circle(int _r):base(_r)
        {
            CS = _r;
        }

        public override int Getarea
        {
            get
            {
                return (_r * _r);
            }


        }
        public override int GetPerm
        {
            get
            {
                return (2* _csc * _csc);
            }


        }
        public override void display()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("area of Circle={0}", (_r * _r));
            Console.WriteLine("perimeter of rectangle={0}", (2 * _r * _r));
        }
        public override int CS
        {
            //get
            //{
            //    return _csc;
            //}

            set
            {
                _csc = value;
            }
        }

    }

class Rectangle:Figures
    {
        int _L, _csr;
        public Rectangle(int _L,int _W):base(_W)
        {
         this._L = _L;
            CS = _W;
        }
        public override int Getarea
        {
            get
            {
                return _csr * _L;
            }


        }
        public override int GetPerm
        {
            get
            {
                return (2* _csr * _L);

            }



        }
        public override void display()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("area of rectangle={0}", (_csr * _L));
            Console.WriteLine("perimeter of rectangle={0}", (2* _csr * _L));
        }
        public override int CS
        {
            //get
            //{
            //    return _csr;
            //}

            set
            {
                _csr = value;
            }
        }
}
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Figures f = new Rectangle(3, 4);
            f.display();
            //f.CS = 5;
            f.display();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Marcus i am not able to make reference Variable of the Interface Ifigure make Object of Rectangle and Circle Class could u help me in this !!

Comment: @henk  i am not able to make reference Variable of the Interface Ifigure make Object of Rectangle and Circle Class could u help me in this !!

Comment: @Corak i am not able to make reference Variable of the Interface Ifigure could u help me in this and make Object of Rectangle and Circle Class !!